# CodeIgniter/PyroCMS Form Animation Without Redirect

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a simple e-mail submission field in the footer of a PyroCMS installation I am working on. The desired effect is that when a user enters their e-mail address, and clicks the button, the button will animate and the user's view will remain where it is. I have code for the animation, but no matter how I tell the form to redirect or refresh, it returns the user view to the home page upon every submission.

The code from the footer:

```
<script>
$(".email-form .btn_submit").click(function(){
    return false;
    var $this=$(this);
    var width=$this.outerWidth();
    var inputWidth=$this.siblings("input").outerWidth();

    $this.attr("disabled",true);
    $this.text("Subscribing...");

    $this.animate({
        width:width+inputWidth,
        "margin-left":-inputWidth-4
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        //succeed
        $this.text("Success!");

        setTimeout(function(){
            //return to normal
            $this.attr("style","");
            $this.removeAttr("disabled");
            $this.text("Subscribe");
        },2000);
    },3000);

});
</script>
<div class="email-form">
{{ streams:form stream="newsletter_form" mode="new" notify_a="me@sitename.com|email_field" notify_template_a="newsletter" notify_from_a="admin@sitename.com|SiteName" }}
    <form id="" class="crud_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">

        <div style="display:none;">
            <input type="hidden" value="11" name="stream_id"></input>
        </div>

        {{ fields }}
            <tr class="{{ odd_even }}">
            <td>{{ error }}{{ input }}</td>
            </tr>
        {{ /fields }}

        <input type="submit" class="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="JOIN"></input>

    </form>

{{ /streams:form }}
</div>
```